# FusedLocationProviderClient giving noisy location data

Tags: android, geolocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I have been using the FusedLocationProviderClient (FLP) and testing it's accuray.
I keep getting systematic erratic readings. I suspect it's location fixes provided by cell towers, but they are far too noisy. Does anyone else have this problem?

If so, how can it be fixed?

I'm not sure if I have to implement a filter outside of it, I don't necessarily want to, I believe the FLP is smarter than I, or at least the team of engineers who implemented it are.

Here is an image of data when I was stationary during the sampling period.

[image]

---

**Update**

So beyond adding high accuracy priority on the location request, I had to manually filter `Location` objects on their accuracy property `location.getAccuracy()`. Some locations like the ones in the picture above were around 1km away from true location and they would occur every so often adding a lot of noise to running calculations like distance travelled etc...

Comment: Are you getting location at high accuracy ?

Comment: Yes I am putting high accuracy on the location request